# Wrapping Speex format in an Ogg container..HowTo?

Tags: speex, oggvorbis

I'm looking for examples on how to wrap the speex format with the ogg format.
I stumbled upon the "fish" example (kfish)

but it would be nice if someone could point me in the direction of a "cut to the bone" example, if one exists.
Or perhaps someone could explain how to extend the encoding sample in the manual. Here:
[sample_enc.c   See page 35](http://www.speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual.pdf)
with an ogg container wrapper?
I also took a look at Cliff's page. Here:
[Cliff's page](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/tag/speex/)
But i'm still stranded with naked speex data. Need ogg pants!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to look at are the speexenc.c and speexdec.c utilities that are shipped with Speex.

Comment: Thanks i did.
I managed to link to the files and call encode and decode.